Time span in Tibble
I have a list of records of cars per hour that I summarise per day.
I would like also for each day to record the hour of the first and last record.
I am trying this:
data_per_day <- data_per_hour %>%
  group_by(date_loc = lubridate::date(date_loc)) %>% 
  summarise(sum_cars = sum(car),
            count_start = min(hour(date_loc)),
            count_last = max(hour(date_loc)),
            year_day = yday(first(date_loc)))

However, count_start and count_last are always 0.
What am I doing wrong?

It'll be hard to answer without some example data. Are we to assume that data_per_hour$date_loc is formatted as POSIXct datetimes?

I just realized (overnight ;-) ) that I needed to use group_by(date_loc_dt = lubridate::date(date_loc)), creating a new variable date_loc_dt  rather than overwiting date_loc.

Good catch! The group_by is converting your datetimes to dates, which when queried by lubridate::hour will have an hour of 0. e.g. lubridate::hour(as.Date("2024-05-12"))

The following solution worked:
data_per_day <- data_per_hour %>%
  group_by(date_loc_dt = lubridate::date(date_loc)) %>% 
  summarise(sum_cars = sum(car),
            count_start = min(hour(date_loc)),
            count_last = max(hour(date_loc)),
            year_day = yday(first(date_loc)))

The previous code was overwriting date_loc. Using the new variable date_loc_dt solved the issue.
Thank you to @JonSpring for confirmation.

You could approach it this way. Here's an example:
ab <- data.frame(a=rep(c("01/01/2024", "12/31/2024"), each=10), b = sample(1:20, 20, T))
ab$a <- as.Date(ab$a, format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin="1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

If you have a dataset such as ab, you could generate row numbers as shown below using mutate. Variable c would be analogous to hours per day. You do not have to create it if such a column already exists. Then, you could obtain the record for first and last hour of each day using filter.
library(tidyverse)
abc <- ab %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(d = as.numeric(factor(a, levels = unique(a))))
abc %>% filter(c==min(c))
abc %>% filter(c==max(c))

Similarly, you can convert your dates to factor and then to numeric to generate a sequence of numbers that uniquely represent the dates in your dataset. You could then use them in group_by before summarise
abc %>% group_by(d) %>% summarise(sum_b = sum(b))

